# Does 'Conditional Independence' means there should be no multicollinearity among features?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, assumptions, naive-bayes

I was reading the Naive Bayes article on Wikipedia and I read that, In Naive Bayes, the naive assumption that Naive Bayes make is "each feature is conditionally independent of every other feature, given the category Ck". So, I was wondering if 'Conditional Independence' means there should be no multicollinearity among features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not imply lack of multicolineaity. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normal with variance 0.001, and have mean $\mu = 100$ if $Z = 1$ and mean $\mu = -100$ if $Z = 0$, but are conditionally independent given $Z$. There is still extreme multicolineairty here, with the correlation being very close to $1$.

Comment: So, What could be an intuitive explanation of conditional independence in Naive Bayes?

Comment: @AkashDubey I fail to see how multicollinearity has anything to do with conditional independence or Naive Bayes here. Are you running into this problem with a data analysis? As an example, two factors can have 0 prevalence but be conditionally independent, as such both terms are nominally multicollinear, but not necessarily dependent.

Comment: @AkashDubey conditional independence states that *if you knew $Z$* in this example, then they are independent. This implies that *at every fixed level of $Z$* in the above example, you will not have multicolinearity. But you can still have multicolinearity if you ignore $Z$.